# How escape spaces and "&" characters in the selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I would like to escape spaces and `&` in an id selector:

```
$("input[name='TherapeuticArea']").click(function () {
    var area = $(this).val(); // = "first & last"
    $("div[id=" + area + ']').show();
});
```

Comment: Simpler solution, don't put spaces and `&` symbols in your `id` attributes; encode them first if you need. It's also worth noting that spaces are not permitted in `id` attributes - even in HTML5's much more permissive model.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a clean `data-value="first-last"` and using `$(this).data('value')`

So your code would look like:

HTML

```
<input name="TherapeuticArea" value="First & last" data-value="first-last">
```

JS

```
$("input[name='TherapeuticArea']").click(function () {
    var area = $(this).data('value');
    $("div[id=" + area + ']').show();
});
```